# How to check lines from a file in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I am have I question regarding my beginner bank account login.  I created a file for the usernames and passwords to be stored in and I need to check if the user has the correct info.  I can't seem to get it to recognize when the info is correct.  I am at a lost on what to do.

```
combine = str(signup)+'_'+signpass
json.dump(combine,open('C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Database.txt','a'))
account = ''
username=''
password=''
fob = open('C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Database.txt','r')
account = int(raw_input('Enter in your account number... '))
print 'Great'
time.sleep(1)
password=raw_input('Enter in your password... ')
accounter = str(account)+ '_'+password
if accounter in fob:
    print 'You are in!!'
else:
    print 'Why did it not work?!'
```

This is just a little bit of the code, but I think this is all you need to help me.  Thanks so much in advance!!

Comment: No this is my own motivation to try to learn the language.

Comment: Probably line end characters in the file. Did you look into the file and see how `json` actually dumps your data, or how the content looks after you read the file back in? As an aside, storing passwords like this is a rather horrible idea. Never do this in practice.

Comment: Try storing the password as a md5 hash.

Comment: Try using json.loads to load the file. Discover how to create a json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open() creates a file handle, but does not read from it. You need additional code to read it. Assuming all the logins are stored on a single line:

```
fob = open('C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Database.txt','r')
logins = fob.readline()
fob.close()
#...
if accounter in logins:
    print 'You are in!!'
else:
    print 'Why did it not work?!'
```

For more information, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Did you try this? I don't think it will work. It seems the way OP stores the pwd, they all end up in one line looking like this: `'"name_pwd""name2_pwd2"'`. It might work if you change it to `logins = fob.readline()`, i.e. just the first line.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit accordingly

Comment: +1 Still horrible way to store and retrieve passwords, but it works. :-)

Comment: Yes I tried it and it didn't work unfortunately so I was wondering how to get the readline() to know what was the most recent line?  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it worked! I messed up with the fob.readline()!  Thanks for your help to a lost beginner!

Answer (score 1):

## Review of OP code

### backslash in file name

'C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Database.txt' will not work as `\` is escape. You shall use either raw string prefix r'C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Database.txt', double escape by 'C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Database.txt' or with file names you may often use forward slashes (this works mostly on MS Windows too and is my favourite way).

### Closing files safely

If you open a file, it is good practice to close it.
Learn the idiom:

```
with open(fname, "r") as f:
    # use the `f` here, e.g.
    print f.read()
```

This safely closes the file at the moment the inner block is left.

### File object is not file content

When you open a file, you get "file like object". This is sort of handle for open file, but not actual content.

You shall use methods like `read()` etc. to get the content.

## `dbman.py`

Following code allows managing user names and passwords stored in JSON file:

```
"""dbman.py - account db manager
Usage:
    dbman.py [-f <fname>] list
    dbman.py [-f <fname>] add <accountid> <passwd>
    dbman.py [-f <fname>] check <accountid> <passwd>

Options:
    --fname, -f <fname>  Name of credential file name
                         [default: accountdb.json]
"""
import json

def dbadd(fname, accid, passwd):
    try:
        with open(fname) as f:
            db = json.load(f)
    except IOError:
        # File does not exist
        db = {}
    #update the database in memory
    db[accid] = passwd
    #save it to disk    
    with open(fname, "w") as f:
        json.dump(db, f)

def dblist(fname):
    try:
        with open(fname) as f:
            db = json.load(f)
        for accid, passwd in db.items():
            print "Account: {accid}: Password: {passwd}".format(accid=accid, passwd=passwd)
    except IOError:
        print "DB file not found."

def dbcheck(fname, accid, passwd):
    try:
        with open(fname) as f:
            db = json.load(f)
    except IOError:
        # File does not exist
        db = {}
    if accid not in db:
        print "Given account id does not exist"
        return
    if db[accid] == passwd:
        print "You are in and you know your password!!"
    else:
        print "You are in, but have different password."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    # print args
    fname = args["--fname"]
    accid = args["<accountid>"]
    passwd = args["<passwd>"]
    if args["add"]:
        dbadd(fname, accid, passwd)
    elif args["list"]:
        dblist(fname)
    elif args["check"]:
        dbcheck(fname, accid, passwd)
```

### Run it

To run it, you need to have `docopt` package installed:

```
$ pip install docopt
```

Then you can run it:

See basic usage instructions:

```
$ python dbman.py 
Usage:
    dbman.py [-f <fname>] list
    dbman.py [-f <fname>] add <accountid> <passwd>
    dbman.py [-f <fname>] check <accountid> <passwd>
```

Get complete help string:

```
$ python dbman.py -h
dbman.py - account db manager
Usage:
    dbman.py [-f <fname>] list
    dbman.py [-f <fname>] add <accountid> <passwd>
    dbman.py [-f <fname>] check <accountid> <passwd>

Options:
    --fname, -f <fname>  Name of credential file name
                         [default: accountdb.json]
```

Add some accounts:

```
$ python dbman.py add 77 secret
$ python dbman.py add 88 public
```

List what is known:

```
$ python dbman.py list
Account: 77: Password: secret
Account: 88: Password: public
```

Check, if you know your user name and password:

```
$ python dbman.py check 77 forgotten
You are in, but have different password.
```